# Writing QGIS script to load Output file to Map Project with Desired Name?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis

The following line of code produces the output as a shapefile with the name I want ("MyFile") and where I want it ("path"),

```
path = "/Users/User1/Desktop/"
processing.runandload('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', Input, path+'MyFile.shp')
```

The actual new output shapefile has been saved on my Desktop with the name "MyFile".

However, the "andload" part of "runandload" places the output ON MY MAP PROJECT with the name "Selection", not "MyFile".

This becomes a problem later in my script if I generate another output file, it too gets added to the map project with the name "Selection", making it impossible to choose between them for subsequent processing.

How should my script be written to load output to the map project with the desired name?

Comment: Why not using `setLayerName()` method to rename the layer ([see here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140749/rename-layers-with-script))?

Comment: Props @wiltomap. Still seems strange the output loads without the name I assign it but this extra step is the practical workaround that achieves what I need. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to rename the layer, you could use the following code to load the output that's saved directly into your map project and assign it any `name` you wish. No need to use `runandload` and the only two parameters that you may want to change would be the `name` and the directory in the `path`:

```
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorLayer
name = 'MyFile'
path = "/Users/User1/Desktop/" + name + '.shp'

processing.runalg('qgis:saveselectedfeatures', Input, path)
layer = QgsVectorLayer(path, name, "ogr")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```