# How do I trim the first 5 characters of several layernames at once?

Tags: qgis, layer-name

Due to a clip-batchprocess and the tool "package layers" I end up with a geopackage with several layernames that start with "clip_". I would like to trim all the layernames by the first 5 characters instead of manually changing all the layernames. How can I do that?

[image]

I tried to use the following expression in the python console:

```
layerList = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()
for layer in layerList:
    basename = layer.name()
    layer.setName(basename.replace("clip_",""))
```

But it doesn't work for me. The layer names don't change.

[image]

Comment: Have a look to this solution which will do the trick: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/329863/87346

Comment: Depends on whether these layers are loaded or not ... Could u make the context a bit more clear @Enzo Baldini ?

Comment: @Snaileater I can load the layers in the QGIS project if necessary. But the result should be to change the layer names in the geopackage (*.gpkg). I would like to have "bfn_ffh_gebiete" & "bfn_landschaftsschutzgebiete" etc. as the new layernames. This means to delete the first five charachters ("clip_") from each layername.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably some sort of rules/agreements that sit behind the GeoPackage term in QGIS environment, because all imported vector and also attribute objects will have a prefix based on the `.gpkg`-file name and an empty space i.e. `'example layer_name'` (example taken from: https://github.com/ngageoint/GeoPackage/blob/master/docs/examples/java/example.gpkg), but this does not work for rasters, see image below.

[image: example]

When I used your code:

```py
layerList = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()
for layer in layerList:
    basename = layer.name()
    layer.setName(basename.replace("example ","_"))
```

I got the following result:

[image: result]

So, I would assume you simply need to get the name of GeoPackage itself:

```py
import os

layerList = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot().findLayers()

for layer in layerList:
    source = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer().dataProvider().dataSourceUri()
    geopackage_path = os.path.normpath(source.split('|')[0])
    geopackage_name = geopackage_path.split(os.sep)[-1].split('.')[0]
    basename = layer.name()
    layer.setName(basename.replace("{} _clip".format(geopackage_name),"_"))
```

---

**References:**

- [PyQGIS Developer Cookbook | 3. Loading Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#vector-layers)