# Using the same file name as input layer in MMQGIS KML Export

Tags: qgis, kml, mmqgis

I have a bulk of data, which I would like to export as the KML file by using the MMQGIS plugin.

[image]

Everything is fine with the plugin, but I am wondering about auto-change the output file name, which could be based on the input layer name. Is it possible at all?

Comment: I bet it's to export Eclipse data ! Just by curiosity, why export KML with MMQGIS and not with the "Save as ..." QGIS native function ? Is it for the HTML description ?

Comment: I have to use the MMQGIS because of the fill color. The standard KML export in QGIS results in the empty polygon only without fill. Yes, you were right, it's for eclipse data. However, I am looking forward to the solution also towards another, eclipse-free situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under QGIS, once you installed MMQGIS plugin, you can open a Python console editor and adapt the code below :

```py
from mmqgis.mmqgis_dialogs import mmqgis_kml_export_dialog

# you can adapt the code by iterate over all the project layer
# for e.g. to retrieve the active layer name
# layer_name = iface.activeLayer().name()
layer_name = "16h37m20"

# create a mmqgis kml export dialog class instance
kml_export = mmqgis_kml_export_dialog(iface)
# search layer name in the dialog combobox
layer_index = kml_export.input_layer_name.findText(layer_name)
# if layer name is not found in the dialog combobox
if layer_index == -1:
    raise ValueError("Layer not found")
else:
    kml_export.input_layer_name.setCurrentIndex(layer_index)
    # set the output kml file path
    kml_export.output_file_name.setFilePath(fr"C:/folder1/folder2/{layer_name}.kml")
    kml_export.run()
```

Comment: It throws error. Anyway, I am thinking also about combination it with rename an active layer. I have code like this:
for layer in iface.layerTreeView().selectedLayers():
    layer.setName('16h45m00s')
then we could do sth like this:
layer_name = layer.setName

Comment: it would be more something like `layer_name = layer.name()`. And the error, is it the `Layer not found` error ?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.12\apps\Python37\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 18
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: I added a `r` in front of path to consider the path string as raw, I think the error will disappear.

Comment: Now is fine. I have combined it also with the code presented here:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140749/rename-layers-with-pyqgis-script
and works really smoothly :)

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by changing the source code of the plugin. Otherwise, the plugin uses the name `temp` for each output file.

Open `mmqgis_dialogs.py` file in MMQGIS Plugin folder (`Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder`, navigate to `python/plugins/mmqgis`)

Change `mmqgis_temp_file_name` method (line ~260) in `mmqgis_dialog` class as follows:

```py
def mmqgis_temp_file_name(self, suffix, name=None):
    project = QgsProject.instance()

    home_path = project.homePath()
    if not home_path:
        home_path = os.getcwd()

    for x in range(1, 10):
        if name:
            name = home_path + "/" + name + str(x) + suffix
        else:
            name = home_path + "/temp" + str(x) + suffix
        if not os.path.isfile(name):
            return name

    return home_path + "/temp" + suffix
```

Find and change the following line (between approx. line 2170-2175):

```py
self.output_file_name.setFilePath(self.mmqgis_temp_file_name(".kml"))
```

to

```py
self.output_file_name.setFilePath(self.mmqgis_temp_file_name(".kml", self.input_layer_name.currentText()))
```

And add the following line (same as above) to `changelayers` method (approx. line 2175-2180):

```py
self.output_file_name.setFilePath(self.mmqgis_temp_file_name(".kml", self.input_layer_name.currentText()))
```

[image]

Comment: Something is missing, still the same

Comment: I tried tyour method twice, but after reopening QGIS says that he couldn't load MMQGIS plugin due to an error when calling its classFactory()

Comment: Is the plugin updated. I downloaded it today, made changes in the latest version and it worked.

Comment: @MKR what is the error message? –

Comment: I try in Windows10 and Ubuntu, it works.

Comment: hmm possibly not, as some lines weren't accurately to yours. Let me update it and I will back to your solution in the future because it looks really promising.